# Facebook Bot doesn't return message correctly except facebook app admin

Tags: php, facebook, chatbot, facebook-apps, facebook-chatbot

I've created a **bot in PHP for Facebook Messenger** and after it was submitted I got a problem. Bot **responds correctly to admins** on the Facebook app, but when a subscriber writes to it, he takes as a response **[get_started payload]** in every intent or doesn't take a response.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide more information in the question. Is your app live? Did your app pass Review? Does your PHP handle based on user IDs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i fixed it couple weeks ago and the problem was that i didn't get profile information correctly

Comment: Glad to hear that. You could answer your own question to help others who might face the same situation, and shows that this question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I didn't save correctly public profile information for subscriber in my db and ID of person comes empty. By default Facebook send get_started payload if you send a message with empty sender